# Objective-C date formatting from core data

Tags: ios

My core data entity has a date field which I can output to a UITableViewCell and it outputs like this:

[image: date]

What I'd like to do is change this date format so that it is a bit more human readable, e.g. to

Friday 19th October 14:44

or

19/10/2012 14:44

How do I do this in Objective-C? I imagine there's a formatter class for NSDate but how do I convert the pulled core data string to an NSDate?

Comment: [NSDateFormatter...](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Also, why store the date as a string if core data entities can have NSDate attributes?

Comment: You're right - I hadn't realised that. I have changed to an NSDate so now just need to know how to format it so it's a bit better on screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the above answers worked, even when I tried to cast the core data object to a NSDate it still wouldn't perform the cast. I ended up doing this:

```
// Make a date formatter which corresponds exactly with the format of the date in core data
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];

// Get the date from core data
NSString *dateStr = [[object valueForKey:@"date"] description];

// Parse from string to date
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr ];

// Set the date formatter to the format that I actually want
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy HH:mm"];

// Set the text on the date label
cell.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

It may need to be adjusted for locale to locale, I haven't tested it as I don't have a machine capable of compiling the code with me.

```
- (NSString *)dateAsString:(NSDate *)theDate {

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle]; 
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

return  [df stringFromDate:theDate];
}
```